# Show something only in landscape mode Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement something similar to how Facebook implemented their landscape mode for their iOS app.

[image: Facebook Landscape]

In landscape mode, on the right side there is a persistent right panel. In portrait mode, only the news feed shows. How can I implement something like this?

Comment: you need to implement size clases or create and adaptive layout [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) is  a great tutorial

Comment: @UmairAfzal Size classes won't help, since the iPad has the same horizontal/vertical size classes regardless of orientation.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing provided by the SDK to do what you want (`UISplitViewController` is close, but opposite of what you're asking about).  So you'll have to use a custom container view controller to do this.  I would suggest checking out the [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1) part of the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/).